# hyphen converts into comma in web-scraping

Tags: javascript, web-scraping

I am scraping data from page with help of JavaScript & displaying on fancybox popup.

```
var str = "$26.61 - Framed bulletin board offers a self-stick surface for quick and easy note positioning, repositioning, and removing.";
```

When I output it, however, I get this:

```
$26.61 , Framed bulletin board offers a self,stick surface for quick and easy note positioning, repositioning, and removing.
```

Here is some javascript:

```
var pro_desc = $('meta[name=Description]').attr("content");
var shortDesc = $.trim(pro_desc).substring(0, 225);
var count1 = shortDesc.search(/$/i);
if(count1!=-1) {
    var short_desc1 = shortDesc.replace("$", "");
    var short_desc2 = short_desc1.split("-");
    var desc1 = short_desc2;
} else { 
    alert('In Else Section---'+shortDesc);
} 
var product_description = desc1;
alert(product_description);
```

Why does my output have `,`'s instead of `-`'s?

Comment: Can you post some of the javascript you've used?

Comment: var pro_desc = $('meta[name=Description]').attr("content");

var shortDesc = $.trim(pro_desc).substring(0, 225)

var count1 = shortDesc.search(/$/i); 

if(count1!=-1)
{
 var short_desc1 = shortDesc.replace("$", "");
 var short_desc2 = short_desc1.split("-");
 var desc1 = short_desc2;
}
else
{
 alert('In Else Section---'+shortDesc);
}

var product_description = desc2;

alert(product_description);

Comment: i am scrapping data from meta description but it's not displaying data same as meta content it adds comma instead of hyphen...

Comment: What happened to `desc2`?  It's never declared in you Javascript.

Comment: sorry it was by mistake,plz check now updated code above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why does my output have `,`'s instead of `-`'s?

You are **splitting** on hyphens:

```
var short_desc2 = short_desc1.split("-");
```

So `short_desc2` is an array containing strings, each of which was separated from the other by a hyphen. Example:

```
'foo-bar'.split('-');
// returns the array ['foo', 'bar']
```

Now, when you `alert` an array (`alert(product_description);`), i.e. convert it back to a string, the elements are concatenated with a comma in between:

```
alert('foo-bar'.split('-'))
// alerts 'foo,bar'
// or
alert([1,2,3]);
// alerts '1,2,3'
```

It's the same as doing:

```
alert(arr.join(','));
```